# Invalid characters in XML feed data

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a feed that I pull data into a database from. It provides the data in XML format. However, the data includes "illegal" characters. For example:

```
A GREAT NEIGHBOURHOOD â€“ WITH A
```

or

```
large â€œcountry styleâ€ eat-in
```

or

```
Garage 14â€™x32â€™, large
```

or

```
 ORâ€¦â€¦.ENDLESS POSSIBILITIES!!
```

My question is first, how do I identify the encoding of these characters, and second, how do I change the encoding to match the UTF8 format expected by my database?

EDIT: To be clear, there's no database involved in this process (at this point in the process, anyway). The data will be inserted into the DB later, but at the moment I'm just reading the data via a PHP script and printing it on screen using `var_dump`.

EDIT 2: the data is being pulled from a RETS feed using the PHP [PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) library

Comment: What's the exact problem? Doesn't the feed declare its own encoding, either with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` or with HTTP headers?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález-- no, the encoding is not declared-- it's assumed to be UTF8 though some feed providers don't really get this right.

Comment: But those characters look like actual UTF-8, being misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 :-?

Comment: Please provide some code that indicates how you are receiving the XML data and putting it into your database.  It may be as simple as using the wrong version of a library function that enforces the wrong encoding (PHP is full of such hidden traps)

Comment: @user101289 where do you pull the data from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your UTF-8 response is treated in a different way or the database is not set up correctly. Here some examples on where this could happen and how to fix it.

**Before Using Curl**

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

**Mysql (my.cnf)**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

**When Creating The Database Manually**

```
CREATE DATABASE `your_table_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci;
```

**When Using Frameworks such as Doctrine**

```
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '*****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(1002=>'SET NAMES utf8')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that at some point the XML source or data, that is UTF-8, is treated as ISO-8859-1 and converted to UTF-8. Depending on how you generate the feed this could happen at several points.

The most likely point is the encoding for the database connection. Make sure it is UTF-8.

Another possibility is the content type header you send.

Answer (score 4):

Please add your database encoding type so we can answer better.

In order to detect the encoding type of a string you will need to use the [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) as follow:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding("your-string");
```

You can also use this function to convert from one encoding type to another,

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, $source_encode, $destination_encode);
```